How can I talk to the professor who has accused me of cheating?
My professor gave me a course incomplete because my lab3 homework on GitHub is very similar to someone else’s work. I would admit that I did asked former students from this course to send me the lab3 answer but I just used it to learn the course material, I never submit it for any grading. One month later after I understood the correct logic of this lab3, I pushed my slightly modified version to GitHub so that I can review for final exam. The professor is asking me the source of my code for lab3 and I am afraid that he might accuse me of academic misconduct.
BTW, he did emphasize more than once that we should not look or copy other people’s code. Even though I did somehow broke the rule, I did not submit lab3 for grading. I only used it to help me learn faster because I encountered a mental crisis this semester due to my brother’s death and so I missed a lot of school work. I looked at other’s code only to help me learn faster. What should I do about it? And how should I explain it to my professor.

so you received a completed homework assignment from another student, did not actually submit any work for that assignment, and then uploaded (a slightly modified version of) the other student's work to your GitHub account? And part of the rules for this course were that, not only can you not copy another student's code, but you also can't look at it?

The post is significantly improved after your edit. But, I'm still not entirely sure what question you would like us to answer. If it is the title question, that may be a duplicate of: How should I phrase an important question that I need to ask a professor?

To answer Esther's question: YES. I have again looked at the class policy and it say clearly we are not allowed to look at other people's code before or when we are writing our own code. Otherwise, it is deemed as cheating. However, I did not obtain any benefit for my self even though I looked at other's code.

To answer cag51's question: I wonder how I can communicate to the professor so that he could actually believe that I never had the intention of cheating in this course and how I can convenience that I looked at other people's code only for learning purposes and should not be deemed as cheating.

@Leeee Why would you describe it to the professor any differently than you're describing it to us? If you're looking for a code phrase, that doesn't exist for this situation any more than it does for asking Helen Mirren on a date; however creative you are she doesn't have to say yes. Whatever you say to your professor they don't have to believe you if you've run afoul of rules.

I don’t quite understand the situation. The title says the professor accused you, the body says you are afraid they might accuse you. Those are quite different situations to be in.

Professors are humans, so you talk to them like you would talk to other humans. Depending on the local culture, you need to take more or less care of the difference in status. Like all other humans it is unknown how they will respond.

I actually felt very sorry for what I did even though I did not really cheat in this course. To be honest, I would say learning faster by looking at other's code indeed violates the class policy although it did not help me earn better grade for my assignment. I think I would just be as candid as possible with the professor and if there is still any consequence, I will accept it.
